# Footer Buttons not visible when deriving from own Dialog

Tags: dialog, sapui5

I am reusing my own Dialog "class" for different dialogs. This custom dialog is derived from sap.m.Dialog. Since OpenUI5 Version 1.34.* the footer buttons are no longer visible when following this approach.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/vobitijezu/edit?html,js,output

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the dialog is a control, I had to shift the code to the init method. After that, the dialog showed the footer buttons like a charm.

Hope this helps someone in my situation, too.

Anton